# trying to use takeUnretainedValue() in swift 2

Tags: swift2

that was my code in swift 1.2

```
let record = attendee.ABRecordWithAddressBook(addressBookController.adbk)!
let unmanagedValue = ABRecordCopyValue(record.takeUnretainedValue(), kABPersonEmailProperty)
```

I get an error message now

```
Value of type 'ABrecord' has no member 'takeUnretainedValue'
```

what's the alternative then?

Answer (score 3):

I actually had a similar problem with the line:

```
let retrievedData : NSData = dataTypeRef!.takeRetainedValue() as! NSData
```

Which compiled after I simply removed the .takeRetainedValue().

Probably because dataTypeRef! is unwrapped already.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is very clear. You can't say `takeUnretainedValue` to an `ABRecord?`.

Here's the declaration:

```
ABRecordWithAddressBook(_ addressBook: ABAddressBook) -> ABRecord?
```

So this thing yields an Optional. You have to unwrap it. This might work:

```
if let record = attendee.ABRecordWithAddressBook(addressBookController.adbk) {
    let unmanagedValue = ABRecordCopyValue(record.takeUnretainedValue(), kABPersonEmailProperty)
}
```

But then I expect you'll have a new problem; you now have the actual ABRecord, completely with memory management. So you should also cut the `takeUnretainedValue()`, leaving this:

```
if let record = attendee.ABRecordWithAddressBook(addressBookController.adbk) {
    let unmanagedValue = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonEmailProperty)
}
```

Comment: So now just cut `.takeUnretainedValue()`.

Comment: can you edit your answer so i can mark it as the correct one

Comment: Sure, happy to do it (if I can just remember what this was about :)